# How might I verify that every instance of a given class is destructed by application termination?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, visual-studio-2012, global-variables

I wrote a simplistic `DBResourceMonitor` class which is used by a set of database classes.  When an instance of one of my database classes is created, it registers itself, and when destroyed, it unregisters itself with a singleton instance of `DBResourceMonitor`.  When the application terminates, that global instance of `DBResrouceMonitor` is destroyed, which checks to make sure that there are no remaining registered instances of any of the classes that it monitors (i.e. that for every register, a unregister was called), and issues a TRACE output and ASSERT if there was a mismatch.

This is all well and good... until I put a couple of these database objects as members of my global application object.  Hence, both the global application object, and the `DBResourceMonitor` are global singletons, and the application is the first to be constructed, hence the last to be destroyed, and hence when `DBResrouceMonitor` is destroyed, the members of the app object have yet to be unregistered, and so it throws an error indicating that there were mismatched register/unregister calls.

As far as I am aware, there is no way to ensure that the `DBResrouceMonitor` is constructed before the application object (and therefore destroyed afterwards).

Is this correct?  Is there a clever way around that, or a way to rethink the above so that I can still track whether everything was taken care of before the final thread terminates?

Comment: Have a look at Schwartz Counters (aka Nifty Counters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having the objects register/deregister themselves with a singleton, you need to store the references to those objects in a collection property of the Singleton. So instead of doing:

```
var x = new MyDBObject();
```

you would use a factory pattern like:

```
var x = DBResourceMonitor.GetDBObject();
```

and somewhere in DBResourceMonitor you could manage a collection of MyDBObjects

```
MyDBObject GetDBObject()
{
//construct and save a MyDBObject or retrieve one from a list.

}
```

Comment: Cool idea. Seems like it might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You could let the database object be the same as the resource monitor, by having a base class that "registers" the database object in its constructor, and "deregister" it in the (virtual) destructor. This way you can just create the object and not worry about singletons or extra monitor classes. The collection of objects would of course be a private static member in this base class, possibly protected in case of you using multi-threading.

I would also use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) instead of raw pointers, or possibly [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).